# How to classify people's clothes by Gabor filter?

Tags: python, classification, textures, gabor-filter

I'd like to identify person from another using Gabor filter.

It is working fine but I don't understand how to classify.

Does it need for example to SVM as classifier?

I understand from this [paper](https://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/33741640/I01415460.pdf?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DI01415460.pdf&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATUSBJ6BAD2DS6WPD%2F20200330%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200330T140517Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEPb%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCICs6LFBWpUPGuWci6q9btHs2EzxBD5VqXeEgtp3Mf%2FOlAiEAwZkw2y2W6OYmeVPzCjDqOBGLck%2F8LRunnaFQvFTZknEqvQMI7%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAAGgwyNTAzMTg4MTEyMDAiDDwOV9IEtyCVKYzQjyqRA%2BAcXINKqkuYK%2FVb5qV0E4fnFXjRBOrIzyfp5DOrmPMN9wep%2BPqtS6WbQ5ko2R3EgQjzLJ4ry3jxWUmBY9rvSqmiyGHTRzYwE19iTJMo4gTpI6A3gVrVayMj%2BTO9hwZbk4ppaA2NvBDBslwVJ0fNtgDh0KhT56mk4CJRbehV2Dc6EFCxgpLTJ6E7YtcNW55Lv5XZCM2YHIYQwzHIfUrQKbE1DIj5E9gLlkcEa1qLA%2Fm9Kqafluw5rCW1YGj3Nq6KQwWdF4EJGnk%2B5jZB0Y5kxLE3aiYAPHADMaItsxVuJM8ta%2BNGB8QqMJNdPFEDPhc7jBFIGmDWykEZoVWdRut2pSovArlU%2FdWoRjlKmUIBy8s4WYxK%2FRPwfc%2BEla5AICIkKTs7qi8ZyuL28YmDo0otJzhTS589zgHv%2B%2By2Yt%2Fxm2aeDz9rH%2FBWM5Ffka%2FDirHNhmEYXgKUzfVwfPyQjgg316cw%2B9MTHXhb7nuXLb7tArWqcwJqHF2rDGkzxTAUR8YShZ9NrPa7Uy3aWGtxRY98VyAgMIHrh%2FQFOusBKvS4NVsUzhWQpkOp6yy7eXZ36ia%2FbPDT8pLZ%2FGVPCN1l1J8OKSoGum%2B97mGSr9cqWkxaAjWX%2Bq1bjZHCJcIxmsjrBlqUFxkKxaAUSOgw49K3AGjcCw%2FGDlWabmGHANxKSq8rZVPjK5dEciWe4ky2%2FaekWFjISChNrHhhQLu94vitJZvWPj3qt5x2QPQBrBHzXaAryobFcXIGghqFmwlJzmjk%2BnX20RY5DxAxlBv7ImF6MuzfJGPTgKSenC7%2FbMRPsW5SnFhvS4B3zMI%2FxfwB8e3c%2F%2B4JImjsRY4G%2B0OmXO5mASyvV9UmehykxA%3D%3D&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=85c032832c61ff8de13478f77c25092e2758901da9faa305ed90dafedaf3df9c) that it don't need SVM OR another classifier

The full code in real-time(video):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from imutils.video import FPS
# capturing video through webcam
import time
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#video dimension in python-opencv
width = cap.get(3)  # float
height = cap.get(4) # float
print width,height
time.sleep(2.0)
fps = FPS().start()
while(1):
    _, img = cap.read()


    if _ is True:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # img =cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    else:
        continue
    g_kernel = cv2.getGaborKernel((21, 21), 8.0, np.pi / 4, 10.0, 0.5, 0, ktype=cv2.CV_32F)
    # print g_kernel
    filtered_img = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_8UC3, g_kernel)
    # print filtered_img
    # kernel_resized = cv2.resize(g_kernel)




    cv2.imshow("Original Tracking", img)
    cv2.imshow("Color Tracking", filtered_img)
    h, w = g_kernel.shape[:2]
    g_kernel = cv2.resize(g_kernel, (3 * w, 3 * h), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    cv2.imshow('gabor kernel (resized)', g_kernel)
    # cv2.imshow("kernel", g_kernel)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
    fps.update()
    fps.stop()
    print("[INFO] elapsed time: {:.2f}".format(fps.elapsed()))
    print("[INFO] approx. FPS: {:.2f}".format(fps.fps()))
```

please help me

Thank you in advance.